# TypeError: Cannot read properties of null during testing onSubmit

Tags: javascript, firebase, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm trying to test whether text in a submit button changes, after the submit button is clicked on.
Once the submit button is clicked, it follows the typical upload image path and gives me errors related to the parent element.

Here is the test:

```
it("text change within button on load", async () => {
    const user = userEvent.setup();
    const mockFn = jest.fn();
    render(<CreateProfilePhoto handleAddData={mockFn} handleSubmit={mockFn} />);
    const file = new File(["hello"], "hello.png", { type: "image/png" });
    const input = screen.getByTestId("upload-prompt");
    await user.upload(input, file);
    const uploadImage = screen.getByRole("button", { name: /upload image/i });
    await user.click(uploadImage);
    expect(
      screen.getByRole("button", { name: /busy.../i })
    ).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
```

Here is the error:

```
   90 |     await user.upload(input, file);
      91 |     const uploadImage = screen.getByRole("button", { name: /upload image/i });
    > 92 |     await user.click(uploadImage);
         |     ^
      93 |     expect(
      94 |       screen.getByRole("button", { name: /busy.../i })
      95 |     ).toBeInTheDocument();
```

and

```
Profile Photo Create › text change within button on load

    TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'uid')

      57 |       const imageRef = ref(
      58 |         storage,
    > 59 |         "profileImage/" + user.uid + "/profilePhoto"
         |                                ^
      60 |       );
      61 |    
      62 |       uploadBytes(imageRef, image)
```

I tried to add `handleSubmit` through props but i know that its not passed through props so it won't make a difference.
What's causing this error? How do i keep it within the bounds of the unit test?

Edit:
This is really what i'm testing:

```
{isLoading ? "Busy..." : "Upload Image"}
```

which is on the last few lines of this:

```
export default function CreateProfilePhoto({ handleAddData }) {
  const user = auth.currentUser;

  const [image, setImage] = useState();
  const [url, setUrl] = useState("");
  const [imageID, setImageID] = useState();
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

  const [originUrl, setOriginUrl] = useState();

  //To validate image size is less than 3MB
  const [largeImage, setLargeImage] = useState(false);

  //To validate image is there before upload
  const [imageMissing, setImageMissing] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    const work = handleAddData(imageID, url);
    return work;
  }, [imageID, url, handleAddData]);

  const handleImageChange = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.files[0]);
    if (e.target.files[0]) {
      if (e.target.files[0].size > 3000000) {
        setLargeImage(true);
        return;
      } else {
        setLargeImage(false);
        setImage(e.target.files[0]);
      }
    }
    setImageID(e.target.id);
  };

  const handleSubmit = () => {
    if (image) {
      setIsLoading(true);
      setImageMissing(false);
      const imageRef = ref(
        storage,
        "profileImage/" + user.uid + "/profilePhoto"
      );
      uploadBytes(imageRef, image)
        .then(() => {
          getDownloadURL(imageRef)
            .then((url) => {
              setOriginUrl(url);
              setUrl(url.replace("https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com", ""));
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              console.log(error.message, "download URL catch");
              toast.error(error.message);
            });
          setImage(null);
          setIsLoading(false);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error.message, "upload bytes URL");
          toast.error(error.message);
        });
    } else {
      setImageMissing(true);
    }
    console.log(url);
  };

  return (
    <div className="m-5">
      <h3>Profile Picture</h3>
      {largeImage && (
        <p className="text-red-600 text-xs">Image must be 3MB or less</p>
      )}
      {imageMissing && (
        <p className="text-red-600 text-xs">
          Please attach image before upload
        </p>
      )}
      <img
        className="w-20 h-20 rounded-full ring-2 ring-orange-400 p-1 m-2"
        src={`appropriate_URL`}
        alt="Profile"
      />
      <input
        type="file"
        onChange={handleImageChange}
        id="profileImageURL"
        accept="image/png, image/jpeg"
        data-testid="upload-prompt"
      />
      <button
        type="button"
        className="border-2 p-2 hover:border-orange-400"
        onClick={handleSubmit}
      >
        {isLoading ? "Busy..." : "Upload Image"}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: One of the values (I think UID) must be null. Make sure that the field is filled

Comment: How do i pass it is from the test? This value is not passed in this component, its defined by whoever is logged in - its their userID

Comment: @DARSIN Here error says cannot read property of null, it means `user` is null it doesn't have any property named `uid`. `uid` is not null `user` is null. Correct me if wrong. @Coolkid I think you need to check in your code why `user` variable is `null`.

Comment: @sachuverma, just after a user is authenticated, they have ```const user = auth.currentUser``` which taps into their firebase authentication details. This includes, ```user.email```, ```user.displayName``` etc and a ```uid```. I'm using their ```uid``` to create a path in the database. How do i mock and pass their ```user.uid``` so that there is no error?

Comment: @Coolkid You will need to share the snippet that you are testing, but most likely you will need to mock out the module that is fetching the data for you and then give it some dummy data to return.

Comment: @Dakeyras, please send me the relevant links so that i can see how this module can be mocked?

Comment: @Coolkid https://jestjs.io/docs/es6-class-mocks